# When datarow is not visible, it changes it's background color as soon as it's visible again and vice versa

Tags: c#, wpf

I managed that you can set a single row's bg-color to green. But as soon as the row is not visible, it changes the bg-color to `AlternatingRowBackground` i set. Here is my code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Done}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
//...
<DataGrid Name = "DG" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" AlternationCount="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Done" Binding="{Binding Done}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

I'm using WPF and C#

Comment: What's the expected output ?

Comment: Every second row should be lightgrey, and some of them green (marked for some reason). It can be, that there are like 5 green rown in a row, then a lightgrey and a while one, than a green than a lightgrey one (can you follow me?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your use `AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"`. You said, every second row should be colored in lightgrey, than you sad, some of them are green. In my assessment, he (the compiler or so) is confused and dont know what to do, so it changes the color to green and grey. So just remove `AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"`